# Laptop cooling pad with no fan for lap use

Tags: laptop, cooling

I want a lightweight laptop cooling pad with no fan.

My laptop provides sufficient cooling, but that relies on drawing air in from a large grill across the bottom of the unit.  As such, I feel like when I sit it on my lap or a similar surface like a bed, the fabric of my clothes or the blankets cover this grill and make it hard for sufficient airflow to enter, stressing the fans and make the laptop run hotter.

Right now I have an old "Cooler Master" I found in my attic which sort of looks like this model, but is older:
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81IOqBWTwcL._AC_SL1500_.jpg

It appears that this model is not being sold any more and is only available from scalpers for ridiculous prices.

The old model I have is nice in that it is lightweight and has plenty of holes to let airflow through.  The back is also elevated which makes typing easier.  It does NOT have any fans, which is good because I don't want any.  However, it has two problems: one, it apparently is for a 13 inch laptop, so my 17" model sticks substantially over the edges.  But the more annoying problem is that my model has two plastic feed on the back sides and nothing in between, which combined with the weight of my laptop becomes uncomfortable over time and even leaves large red marks on my legs despite wearing heavy denim pants.

I have seen a few pads which appear to be more like stands which adjust to insane angles.   As a result, they have these little things that stick out at the bottom to prevent the computer from falling out which can get in the way of typing a low angles.  I only want a shadow angle with two to three inches max height in the back, and nothing to get in my way when I try to type.

Where can I find something like shown in the above picture for a 17" laptop, except without fans, and for a reasonable price (I'm guessing around $20 or so)?

Answer (score 2):

Check some options that I found on Amazon, mostly from one brand - cooling pads without fans seem to be quite rare.

- [Fellowes Laptop Riser, 13 1/4 x 9 3/8 x 4 1/4, White/Gray](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FL2U8I6) (probably out of production as I can't find it on their website, but from a quick search, it seems that it supports laptops up to 17")
- [Fellowes I-Spire Series Laptop Lift/Stand, Black (9472401)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0114MSBO4)
- [CARNATION Laptop Stand Desk with Phone Stand and Cable Clip. Adjustable, Foldable & Portable Riser. Fully Compatible MacBook Base Holder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07K7P8BGP) (not sure about compatibility, in the reviews someone says it works for his 17" Lenovo)
- [AmazonBasics Ventilated Adjustable Laptop Computer Holder Desk Stand](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00WRDS8H0) (not sure I would recommend this, but has plenty of ratings to check)
- [Fellowes I-Spire Series Laptop Lapdesk, Black (9473101)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0114MT9GI)
- [Fellowes Designer Suites Laptop Riser, Black (8038401)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001C8A7CA)

Comment: I really like the fourth one in the list (the iSpire with the flat surface, but I do NOT like that bumper, as it would be in my way all the time.  I wonder if it's possible to remove it..

Comment: They surely seem removable, but I could not find anywhere if they are designed to be removed. If you decide you are really interested in purchasing it, it would be better to send a message to the manufacturer first to clear it out.

Comment: I read some of the reviews and one of them said they are 3/8" to 1/2" high - if that's the case they might actually not stick out and be in the way.  The picture may have picked an unfortunate example with a computer that is very thin in the front.

Comment: That would be nice. You'd better also check your laptop dimensions, because according to [this review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/RJKYEX8HFVFAC/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B0114MT9GI), you might have issues with a 17" laptop.